# How to take summary from a sql data Table using sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with some data like subtotal,tax,Grand,Date
I want to take summary report from this data using Sql query.
when I use query its getting all the selected date's data (example: if start date 31-07-20, end date 01-08-20) then result showing each days details. My goal is to get summary of each days.

What I am getting:

[image]

What I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Sub) as Sub, SUM(VAT) as VAT, SUM(Grand) as Grand, Date
FROM <WHATEVER>
GROUP BY Date
```

This is SQL 101...